# Is the phrase "bled our country dry" a metaphor? Or some other figure of speech?

Tags: questions, metaphors, figures-of-speech

Is the phrase "bled our country dry" a metaphor? Or some other figure of speech?

Context: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZ_eV2TRlOg&t=175s

Answer (score 1):

bleed someone white and **bleed someone dry**. [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bleed+dry)

> to take all of someone's money; to extort money from someone.

It is metaphorical, a country does not bleed.  It can though be **bled dry** of treasure and life.

Comment: And the metaphor "bleed dry" almost certainly derives from the practice of hanging a slaughtered animal head-down until all the blood drains out.